# How to select certain data points from tkinter table and assign them to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code below that creates a table with information given by the user but I can't find how to select each individual variable and set them aside.

```
import tkinter
from time import sleep

textFont1 = ("Arial", 10, "bold italic")
textFont2 = ("Arial", 16, "bold")
textFont3 = ("Arial", 8, "bold")

class LabelWidget(tkinter.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y, text):
        self.text = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.text.set(text)
        tkinter.Entry.__init__(self, master=master)
        self.config(relief="ridge", font=textFont1,
                    bg="#500000", fg="#ffffff",
                    readonlybackground="#500000",
                    justify='center',width=20,
                    textvariable=self.text,
                    state="readonly")
        self.grid(column=x, row=y)

class EntryWidget(tkinter.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y):
        tkinter.Entry.__init__(self, master=master)
        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.config(textvariable=self.value, width=20,
                    relief="ridge", font=textFont1,
                    bg="#ddddddddd", fg="#000000000",
                    justify='center')
        self.grid(column=x, row=y)
        self.value.set("")

class EntryGrid(tkinter.Tk):

    ''' Dialog box with Entry widgets arranged in columns and rows.'''
    def __init__(self, colList, rowList, title="Enter Information"):
        self.cols = colList[:]
        self.colList = colList[:]
        self.colList.insert(0, "")
        self.rowList = rowList
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(title)

        self.mainFrame = tkinter.Frame(self)
        self.mainFrame.config(padx='3.0m', pady='3.0m')
        self.mainFrame.grid()
        self.make_header()

        self.gridDict = {}
        for i in range(1, len(self.colList)):
            for j in range(len(self.rowList)):
                w = EntryWidget(self.mainFrame, i, j+1)
                self.gridDict[(i-1,j)] = w.value
                def handler(event, col=i-1, row=j):
                    return self.__entryhandler(col, row)
                w.bind(sequence="<FocusOut>", func=handler)
        self.mainloop()

    def make_header(self):
        self.hdrDict = {}
        for i, label in enumerate(self.colList):
            def handler(event, col=i, row=0, text=label):
                return self.__headerhandler(col, row, text)
            w = LabelWidget(self.mainFrame, i, 0, label)
            self.hdrDict[(i,0)] = w
            w.bind(sequence="<KeyRelease>", func=handler)

        for i, label in enumerate(self.rowList):
            def handler(event, col=0, row=i+1, text=label):
                return self.__headerhandler(col, row, text)
            w = LabelWidget(self.mainFrame, 0, i+1, label)
            self.hdrDict[(0,i+1)] = w
            w.bind(sequence="<KeyRelease>", func=handler)

    def __entryhandler(self, col, row):
        s = self.gridDict[(col,row)].get()
        if s.upper().strip() == "EXIT":
            self.destroy()

    def __headerhandler(self, col, row, text):
        ''' has no effect when Entry state=readonly '''
        self.hdrDict[(col,row)].text.set(text)

    def get(self, x, y):
        return self.gridDict[(x,y)].get()

    def set(self, x, y, v):
        self.gridDict[(x,y)].set(v)
        return v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cols = ['Name', 'Location', 'Day', 'Time In', 'Time Out']
    rows = ['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6', '7', '8', '9','10']
    app = EntryGrid(cols, rows)
```

It split up for some reason but, anyway, I would like to have each set of information saved with its like terms so that I can create a schedule afterwards.

Comment: You want something like this `{'Name':'John Doe', 'Location': 'my loacation is at ...', ...}` as result?